# azure AD and Keycloak synchronisation

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

I try to find ressources about how to synchronize user attribut between Keycloak and Azure AD ( like for local AD ) ? I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: Have you able to find it?